# SAN volumes not showing in new cluster

Tags: storage-area-network, failovercluster

Some background.... 
We have 
Two hyper-v hosts running server 2012r2 with a number of guests. 
Msa1040 SAN with two disk pools
The hosts are a two server cluster
The two hosts connect to the san via iScsi for cluster storage.

We’ve had an OS fail on the two host servers and one guest (stuck on black screen on boot up). So I’ve had to reload them. 
I’ve created a 3rd host server to get things up and running.

The san is mapped to svr3 and Svr3 can see the luns via iscsi connector. 
I’ve brought the disks online in disk management. 
I’m trying to add the volumes to a failover cluster. 
The problem is that I cannot see the contents of either of the storage in the cluster storage folder.
The cluster died when the two hosts failed so I’m starting from scratch
Any ideas on things to check or anything obvious that I’ve missed? 
Thanks

Comment: If you add/create a CSV in FoC does it show you the disk as being available for a CSV?

Comment: When I try to add them, it says no suitable disks are available

Answer (score 1):

All sorted.

The volume had a persistent registration on it to the old cluster.
R emove that via PowerShell and happy days

C:\PS>Clear-ClusterDiskReservation -Disk 2